# Are Android Context objects serializable?

Tags: android, static, sharedpreferences, android-context

I declared a non-final static `SharedPreferences` object called `PREFS` together with the other constants in my `Constants.java` class:

```
public static SharedPreferences PREFS = null;
```

My reason for doing so is that my app is comprised of about 6 different `AsyncTasks` that keep accessing the same shared prefs file, and I didn't want to get the `SharedPreferences` and its `Editor` every time. On my app's first run, I make a call to `getSharedPreferences()` in my `MainActivity` and store it to `PREFS` so that it points to an instance before the `AsyncTask`s are fired, and therefore avoid a `NullPointerException`.

However, I kept getting `NullPointerException`s from the `AsyncTask`s anyway. All stack traces point to the line where I make a call to `Constants.PREFS` to get a value. My theory is that after some time, Android kills my app's process, so the next time the alarm for any of my `AsyncTask`s goes off, the value of `Constants.PREFS` would already be `null`.

My question is: Should I make a static variable for `Context` instead? Will its state be persisted even when Android kills off my process? I always pass a reference of `Context` to my `AsyncTask`s when the latter are instantiated so they can call on `getSystemService()`, and that never throws a `NullPointerException`. However, I don't see `Context` extending `Serializable` from the Android docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Application` class to share preferences globally across the application.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static Context mAppContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mAppContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static SharedPreferences getPreferences(){
        return mAppContext.getSharedPreferences("my_app_preferences",MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    }
}
```

Tell android you want your custom Application class, by mentioning it in the manifest:

```
<application android:name=".MyApp" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
```

Now from anywhere, just call

```
MyApp.getPreferences().edit().putBoolean("pref1",true). . . put more stuff . .commit()
```

`MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` ensures all AsyncTask threads get synchronized access to same instance of `SharedPreferences`. Also, `commit()` is atomic, and will persist changes to the disk.

The above pattern is also handy for accessing resources from anywhere.

**Update**

It seems that static reference to context causes troubles with new `Instant Run` feature.

Hence, the context can be required as a parameter of utility method:

```
public static SharedPreferences getPreferences(context){
    return context.getSharedPreferences("my_app_preferences",MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
}
```

Comment: "The above pattern is also handy for accessing resources from anywhere." -- You mean resources of any type? Right now I'm also planning to store/generate the app's UUID string from inside `MyApp`, stored as a private static String.

Comment: By resources I mean, getting Strings from `strings.xml` in res directory. Basically, anything you can get from `Context.getResources()`.

Comment: Hold a second, the method `getApplicationContext()` does not exist from inside `Application`.

Comment: I think App's private preferences are best place to store this UUID (optionally encrypted). In `onCreate()` of `Application` class, you check if this preference exists. if not you generate and save it, if it exists, you verify it.  Also, you can store it in a static variable, in `MyApp` class and share it with rest of application code.

Comment: `Application` class extends `ContextWrapper` which has a public method `getApplicationContext()`. This method is available _inside_ `onCreate()` of `Application` class.